# Android Webview not working2

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

I'm trying to use Android Webview development but for some reason I see a white background, or see the website..):
It's my code, I've brought you everything so you know maybe I was wrong at first 
Thank you very much!

activity_main.xml

```
   <WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>       

</RelativeLayout>
```

WebActivity.java

```
package nerya.web;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    //private Button button;
    private WebView webView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Get webview 
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        startWebView("http://www.androidexample.com/media/webview/login.html");

    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") private void startWebView(String url) {

        //Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
        //When opening a url or click on link

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            //Show loader on url load
            public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog == null) {
                    // in standard case YourActivity.this
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                try{
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
                }catch(Exception exception){
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }); 

         // Javascript inabled on webview  
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

        // Other webview options
        /*
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        */

        /*
         String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
         webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null); 
         */

        //Load url in webview
        webView.loadUrl(url);


    }

    // Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed

    @Override
    // Detect when the back button is pressed
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            // Let the system handle the back button
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package nerya.web;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in                                                                      webview
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        //Show loader on url load
        @Override
         public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
         {

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            try{
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }
            }catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
```